# Actually sending an image file with a iOS notification

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit

I am slightly confused about iOS notifications. I want to schedule a notification with includes an image as its attachment. When I receive the notification on the apple watch I would like to show the image but as I have understood, the apple watch actually needs to have the image in its file system for it to be shown.

Is it possible to actually send the image file with a push notification so that I can save it on the apple watch and show it to the user? Meaning that I don't actually need to have the image on the watch at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually is possible to send an image with the notification payload. This can be done by:

1. Convert an UIImage with the UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image) function to a Data representation of the image
2. Attach the image to the notification by adding it to the notification's UNNotificationContent's userInfo dictionary